# How to extract day, month and year from utcnow?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following var: `time_created = datetime.utcnow()`

How to create a `time_created_day` var from `time_created` that will contain only Y, M, d

like this `datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 7)`

I have the following solution:

```
from datetime import date

time_created_day = date(time_created.year, time_created.month, time_created. day)
```

is it the best way?

Comment: What have you done so far? Tell us the code!

Comment: @ElisByberi done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime.utcnow().date()`

```
datetime.utcnow().date()
datetime.date(2017, 11, 7)
```

Adding to answer

The datetime object always contains year, month, day as well as hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds. It is a combination of  what the date and time objects contain, see [datetime Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

```
from datetime import datetime

# this is your datetime object
time_created = datetime.utcnow()

# when you want to see it formatted as Y,M,D call the date method
date_created = time_created.date()

time_created
date_created
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 7, 23, 43, 43, 761750)
datetime.date(2017, 11, 7)`
```

Comment: Glad to help, If this or another answer solved your question could you please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: how to get datetime(not date) object that will contain Y,m,d?

Comment: I added to my answer based on clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use `time_created.day` to find the day.

```
time_created_day = time_created.day
```

(Similar for month and year)

Comment: I don't want to have `int` var. I want to have datetime object that will have Y, m, d like I show in example

Answer (score 0):

*here it is easiest for you*

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

newdate = year + " " + month + " " + day;
```